# seperating node js into parts for backend

Tags: node.js, backend

I have built a node js app but for simplicity I made two different apps. one does the database product management job for the React frontend such as adding, updating and deleting products and the other does the authentication part with JWT token which is saved in local storage of frontend. in this way I think I'm more comfortable in managing and editing the code I wrote for them because of simplicity and small app size. should I merge the two node js app together?

I know people separate backend from frontend but it came to my mind why not separate backend into parts?

Comment: I do separate my backend into part, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not uncommon to have a separate service for authorization token and resource service (such as OAuth):

[image: oauth schema]

In your case, that looks like a small app, you could definitely group the two to save one process, and refactor later if needed.

If you keep them separated, you will later have [less chance to mix the concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20separation%20of,code%20of%20a%20computer%20program.).

You can also [look at creating distributed npm features](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/build-and-publish-your-first-npm-package-a4daf0e2431) that you plug into your app (as any npm dependencies). This way, you keep things separated and modular.

In this case, you could check [lerna to build a monorepo](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) for your backend service

Comment: I'm hosting my website on a virtual server. It's like a computer that only has a terminal which is accessible from web. so I think it will let me use as mush ports as I want. right? It's an small app for now. but it's going to become bigger and bigger. so in that way, which approach is better?

Comment: I think you should not anticipate too much, and make things when needed,. If splitting the service is a requiremnt for later, then anticipate it, if it's not, then don't waste time to refactor it. At your current step of knowledge, I would recommend to keep them in one process and perhaps starts with a monorepo lerna and keep concerns separated as a module, but not use two node process, which whill makes things a bit more complexe to scale and right now you needs more metrics about your users.